# Visual Studio 2019 C# highlighting not working?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, highlight

Just randomly all syntax highlighting in C# just stopping working and everything looks white and ugly. I've been putting up with it for awhile but it's just really starting to get on my nerves, it's only for C# projects (old and new). Any other language works fine, like C++. I'm really confused to why this is happening in the first place, any ideas? I've tried updating and reinstalling packages, resetting the the fonts and colors options in environment. Here's some screenshots of C# vs C++ as an example, they are just random code from some of my projects to show the highlighting difference.

C#: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7WD6.png

C++: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2fmk.png

Comment: I think it has something to with the update... what version of visual studio are you on? >6.0?

Comment: I'm on version 16.6.1

Answer (score -1):

It's a bug.

Should be solved in the future by MS.

I uninstalled VS2017 last week to install VS2019. I ran it and next I imported my VS2017 settings with black background and yellow/green colors for the editor. And after 2 minutes and tried to restore default settings without success, I uninstalled it and rollbacked the partition and said to me to retry in one to five years...